# Why can't I select whole days from intra-day time series?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-timeindex

I have basic financial OHLCV data.

```
                      Datetime        Open    Volume        date
0    2021-08-25 09:30:00-04:00  149.699997   3524920  2021-08-25
1    2021-08-25 09:35:00-04:00  149.699997   1424746  2021-08-25
2    2021-08-25 09:40:00-04:00  149.785004   1248013  2021-08-25
3    2021-08-25 09:45:00-04:00  149.649994   1208242  2021-08-25
4    2021-08-25 09:50:00-04:00  149.486603   1345607  2021-08-25
```

Let's say I want to select all the examples from one specific day.

```
df["Datetime"].eq("2021-08-25")
```

This doesn't work even though comparisons to string date work when you use lt or gt.

So I created the date column with

```
df["date"] = df["Datetime"].dt.date
```

This new column is than of object dtype yet:

```
df_n["date"].eq("2021-08-25")
```

Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is `'remove'` times, it means set them to `00:00:00` by [`Series.str.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html), because obviously pandas compare strings datetimes with timestamps:

```
df["Datetime"].dt.normalize().eq("2021-08-25")
df["Datetime"].dt.floor('d').eq("2021-08-25")
```

If need compare dates, need dates in another side too:

```
from datetime import date

df["Datetime"].dt.date.eq(date(2021,8,25))
```

Comment: Thanks. I still find it strange as .dt.date returns a column with object dtype a string basically. I don't know why I can't compare.

Comment: @BorutFlis - yes, because `date`s are python objects.

Answer (score 2):

Using strftime can also do

```
df1['Datetime']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Datetime'] )
df1[df1['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')=='2021-08-25']
```